Can you ask Copilot questions with the trial version of https://api.copilot.com/v1/?
So I created my key for Copilot and I can query say the clients...and this works great using curl.  eg
 curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.copilot.com/v1/clients?limit=100' \
 --header 'X-API-KEY: <apikey>' \
 --header 'accept: application/json'

But...I want to be able to converse with Copilot with the api and I'm not seeing a resource to do this at https://docs.copilot.com/reference/getting-started-introduction ?
I asked Copilot itself how to ask a question via REST and it said I could use https://api.copilot.com/v1/ask.  This is odd as I don't see /v1/ask in the documentation.  But I tried this anyways and I get a 403 error:
 curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.copilot.com/v1/ask' \
 --header 'X-API-KEY: <apikey>' \
 --header 'accept: application/json'  \
 -d '{"question": "What are the benefits of using Copilot?"}'

Results:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: rFqfkRCqPLxCOXzUfD7wHpC0ffyubnBSRsLGe1CdZknkJ_HatCLe-Q==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>

But this results in a 403 error.  Is /v1/ask the wrong endpoint?  Is this endpiont only reserved for non-trial users? Do I have a config error?  Any help would be appreciated...the documentation for Copilot isn't that great.
